# Include frutiger font style in TCPDF

Tags: php, fonts, tcpdf

I am generating the PDF using TCPDF. The output I get is in Helvetica font but I want it in Frutiger. I have a `frutiger.otf` file.

I tried the following code

```
$fontname = $pdf->addTTFfont('Frutiger-45Light.otf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
$pdf->SetFont($fontname);
```

I am getting an error: `could not include font definition file`. And I have googled many websites which didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a URL as `fontfile`. It must be a path in the local filesystem.

If you need a font on a different server you first must download it yourself. Since fonts are static you should do this manually.

Comment: please see the edited path ...even i have changed its not working